# Removing Windows Server 2008 Boot loader

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, boot, boot-loader

I'm using XP in my machine. I installed Windows Server 2008 as a second OS using dual boot. But i want to remove Windows Server 2008 and install Windows Server 2003. My greatest problem is to remove Windows Server 2008's boot loader.

How can i remove Windows Server 2008's boot loader?

Thank you

Regards
NLV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the file "bootmgr" in the root of your boot partition.

The post-Vista NTFS boot sector tries to load and run that file, but if it can't find it, it will happily run NTLDR and start the standard NT boot process, just like it used to do before.